# aws lambda@edge + Cloudfront ERROR ()

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

[image: error]

I'm using lambda@edge + cloudfront to do some image resizes etc. My origin is S3 bucket.

**ISSUE:** When I try to call for an object inside s3 via cloudfront over browser I get  the above error (picture). it even happens when I use just a test function(below).

how I call/query it: *My s3 is set as origin, so I just use my cloudfront Domain Name d5hbjkkm17mxgop.cloudfront.net and add s3 path /my_folder/myimage.jpg*

browser url used: d5hbjkkm17mxgop.cloudfront.net/my_folder/myimage.jpg

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    console.log(event);
    console.log("\n\n\n");
    console.log(request);

    callback(null, request);

};
```

I'm pretty sure that request is an object - have no idea why is this happening.
If testing in aws console all works - so it has to be an cloudfront/lambda interface error - because lambda is not even invoked (no new log entrie being generated).

I also have an access error from cloudfront:

```
2018-01-08  12:40:20    CDG50   855 62.65.189.38    GET d3h4fd56s4fs65d4f6somxgyh.cloudfront.net    /nv1_andrej_fake_space/98f741e0b87877c607a6ad0d2b8af7f3ba2f949d7788b07a9e89453043369196 502 -   Mozilla/5.0%2520(X11;%2520Ubuntu;%2520Linux%2520x86_64;%2520rv:57.0)%2520Gecko/20100101%2520Firefox/57.0    -   -   LambdaValidationError   usnOquwt7A0R7JkFD3H6biZp21dqnWwC5szU6tHxKxcHv5ZAU_g6cg==    d3hb8km1omxgyh.cloudfront.net   https   260 0.346   -   TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 LambdaValidationError   HTTP/2.0
```

Any ideas?

**EDITED:** semicolon

Comment: The `CDG` in `CDG50` means you hit a CloudFront edge location near Paris -- CDG in the logs is a reference to [Charles de Gaulle Airport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle_Airport) -- so for this event, your Lambda logs in CloudWatch are probably going to be in Paris (or perhaps London, or Frankfurt), not in us-east-1.  The logs are typically dropped in the nearest region to the edge serving each individual request.

Comment: Is this a viewer request, origin request, origin response, or viewer response trigger?

Comment: sorry I forgot to specify **origin request** trigger

Comment: Also found some logs (in Frankfurt) however they're not much of a help. I can only see **request id**, start, end, and duration of request.

Comment: Isn't there a syntax error at `console.log("\n\n\n") // missing semicolon here`?  It's very critical that you show the actual code that is running.

Comment: Nope, it just gives me warning (tried with semicolon thou, but same result). It is an actual code that I'm trying. I wasn't sure if my prod code is bug free, so I made this easy function. Prod code not working, nor this easy function. Same error.

Comment: Capture the log of an execution with just `console.log(event);`  If the event payload isn't there, something is definitely wrong.  Also check the configuration in the CloudFront console to be sure that the version number of the Lambda function (after `:` in the ARN) is correct.

Comment: if I execute it inside console without cloudfront (testing in console, with my test event) - I see it works correctly. However, as I said trying via cloudfront, when I grab logs from Frankfurt - where it eventually landed i only see id, start and end time, and request duration. ARN version number is correct.

Comment: `console.log('hello, world');`  Verify the basic functionality of the function and logging when invoked from CloudFront.  It doesn't make sense that you see only start/end/duration.  Also, the problem with testing in the console is that this only really tests that the Lambda function doesn't throw an exception -- the returned response isn't parsed for validity against what the CloudFront systems need to see as a response from the function invocation.

Comment: **same error** (I can't even see logs in Frankfurt for now (also checked London, Dublin, and Paris - nothing is there)) but maybe there is some time drift...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Do not forget to **Publish new version** of your Lambda. It is not sufficient to **save** it. Lambda that was last published is the one actually deployed, however you may have different code in aws console window.

**EDIT:** another gotcha - do not forget to change your function version in CloudFront settings. You have to select desired CF distribution that is bind to your Lambda. Choose that CF distribution, then go to **behaviors**, choose **edit** behaviors. Scroll down and last entry is **Lambda Function Associations** (see pic below)

[image]

Last number in **Lambda Function ARN** is the version number of deployed lambda.